# Beamer: how to set right proportions for three groups of plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots

I'm dealing with the following MWE:

```
 \documentclass[dvipsnames, aspectratio=169, 9pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{FiraSans}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} %color extension
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace} 
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}



\begin{filecontents*}{data1.dat}
   t1       a1              t2       a2               t3        a3 
0.142    1.000           0.154    1.000            0.139     0.995
0.284    1.000           0.308    1.000            0.279     0.990
0.426    1.000           0.461    1.000            0.418     0.989
0.569    1.000           0.615    1.000            0.558     0.989
0.711    1.000           0.769    1.000            0.697     0.989
0.853    1.000           0.923    1.000            0.836     0.989
0.995    1.000           1.077    1.000            0.976     0.989
1.137    1.000           1.230    1.000            1.115     0.989
1.279    1.000           1.384    1.000            1.255     0.989
1.422    0.995           1.538    1.000            1.394     0.986
1.564    0.990           1.692    1.000            1.534     0.981  
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{data2.dat}
   t1       a1              t4       a4               t3        a3
3.554    0.920           3.845    0.950            3.485     0.913
3.696    0.915           3.999    0.945            3.625     0.908
3.838    0.910           4.153    0.939            3.764     0.903
3.980    0.905           4.306    0.934            3.904     0.898
4.123    0.900           4.460    0.929            4.043     0.893
4.265    0.895           4.614    0.923            4.182     0.888
4.407    0.890           4.768    0.918            4.322     0.883
4.549    0.885           4.922    0.912            4.461     0.878
4.691    0.880           5.075    0.907            4.601     0.873
4.833    0.875           5.229    0.902            4.740     0.868
4.976    0.870           5.383    0.896            4.880     0.864
5.118    0.865           5.537    0.891            5.019     0.859
5.260    0.860           5.691    0.885            5.158     0.854    
\end{filecontents*}



\begin{filecontents*}{data3.dat}
   t1       a1              t4       a4               t3        a3
3.554    0.920           3.845    0.950            3.485     0.913
3.696    0.915           3.999    0.945            3.625     0.908
3.838    0.910           4.153    0.939            3.764     0.903
3.980    0.905           4.306    0.934            3.904     0.898
4.123    0.900           4.460    0.929            4.043     0.893
4.265    0.895           4.614    0.923            4.182     0.888
4.407    0.890           4.768    0.918            4.322     0.883
4.549    0.885           4.922    0.912            4.461     0.878
4.691    0.880           5.075    0.907            4.601     0.873
4.833    0.875           5.229    0.902            4.740     0.868
4.976    0.870           5.383    0.896            4.880     0.864
5.118    0.865           5.537    0.891            5.019     0.859
5.260    0.860           5.691    0.885            5.158     0.854    
\end{filecontents*}









\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\begin{groupplot}[group style={
    group name=rzrxcomp,
    group size=1 by 3,
    xlabels at=edge bottom,
    ylabels at=edge left,
    vertical sep=4em
    },
    xmin = 0, xmax = 2,
    ymin = 0.8, ymax = 1,
    xtick distance = 0.2,
    ytick distance = 0.2,
    xlabel={$time\;[s]$},
    ylabel={$mass$},
    grid = both,
    grid style = {dotted},
    minor tick num = 1,
    major grid style = {lightgray!75},
    minor grid style = {lightgray!75},
    width = 0.85\textwidth,
    height = 0.50\textwidth,
    %scale only axis,
    %legend cell align = {left},
    %legend pos = north east
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=2},
    legend cell align = {left},
]
    
 \nextgroupplot

\addplot[smooth, black, very thick] table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data1.dat};
\addplot[smooth, Lavender, very thick] table [x = {t2}, y = {a2}] {data1.dat};
\addplot[smooth, Violet, very thick] table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data1.dat};



\nextgroupplot

\addplot[smooth, black, very thick] table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data2.dat};
\addplot[smooth, BurntOrange, dotted, very thick] table [x = {t4}, y = {a4}] {data2.dat};
\addplot[smooth, Violet, very thick] table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data2.dat};



\nextgroupplot[legend entries={n1,n2,n3,n4}]



\addlegendimage{black, very thick, no markers}
\addlegendimage{Lavender, very thick, no markers}
\addlegendimage{Violet, very thick, no markers}
\addlegendimage{BurntOrange, dotted, very thick, no markers}

 
\addplot[smooth, black, very thick] table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data3.dat};
\addplot[smooth, BurntOrange, dotted, very thick] table [x = {t4}, y = {a4}] {data3.dat};
\addplot[smooth, Violet, very thick] table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data3.dat};
  

    
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\begin{groupplot}[group style={
    group name=rzrxcomp,
    group size=1 by 3,
    xlabels at=edge bottom,
    ylabels at=edge left,
    vertical sep=4em
    },
    xmin = 0, xmax = 2,
    ymin = 0.8, ymax = 1,
    xtick distance = 0.2,
    ytick distance = 0.2,
    xlabel={$time\;[s]$},
    ylabel={$mass$},
    grid = both,
    grid style = {dotted},
    minor tick num = 1,
    major grid style = {lightgray!75},
    minor grid style = {lightgray!75},
    width = 0.85\textwidth,
    height = 0.50\textwidth,
    %scale only axis,
    %legend cell align = {left},
    %legend pos = north east
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=2},
    legend cell align = {left},
]
    
 \nextgroupplot

\addplot[smooth, black, very thick] table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data1.dat};
\addplot[smooth, Lavender, very thick] table [x = {t2}, y = {a2}] {data1.dat};
\addplot[smooth, Violet, very thick] table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data1.dat};



\nextgroupplot

\addplot[smooth, black, very thick] table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data2.dat};
\addplot[smooth, BurntOrange, dotted, very thick] table [x = {t4}, y = {a4}] {data2.dat};
\addplot[smooth, Violet, very thick] table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data2.dat};



\nextgroupplot[legend entries={n1,n2,n3,n4}]



\addlegendimage{black, very thick, no markers}
\addlegendimage{Lavender, very thick, no markers}
\addlegendimage{Violet, very thick, no markers}
\addlegendimage{BurntOrange, dotted, very thick, no markers}

 
\addplot[smooth, black, very thick] table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data3.dat};
\addplot[smooth, BurntOrange, dotted, very thick] table [x = {t4}, y = {a4}] {data3.dat};
\addplot[smooth, Violet, very thick] table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data3.dat};
  

    
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\begin{groupplot}[group style={
    group name=rzrxcomp,
    group size=1 by 3,
    xlabels at=edge bottom,
    ylabels at=edge left,
    vertical sep=4em
    },
    xmin = 0, xmax = 2,
    ymin = 0.8, ymax = 1,
    xtick distance = 0.2,
    ytick distance = 0.2,
    xlabel={$time\;[s]$},
    ylabel={$mass$},
    grid = both,
    grid style = {dotted},
    minor tick num = 1,
    major grid style = {lightgray!75},
    minor grid style = {lightgray!75},
    width = 0.85\textwidth,
    height = 0.50\textwidth,
    %scale only axis,
    %legend cell align = {left},
    %legend pos = north east
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=2},
    legend cell align = {left},
]
    
 \nextgroupplot

\addplot[smooth, black, very thick] table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data1.dat};
\addplot[smooth, Lavender, very thick] table [x = {t2}, y = {a2}] {data1.dat};
\addplot[smooth, Violet, very thick] table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data1.dat};



\nextgroupplot

\addplot[smooth, black, very thick] table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data2.dat};
\addplot[smooth, BurntOrange, dotted, very thick] table [x = {t4}, y = {a4}] {data2.dat};
\addplot[smooth, Violet, very thick] table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data2.dat};



\nextgroupplot[legend entries={n1,n2,n3,n4}]



\addlegendimage{black, very thick, no markers}
\addlegendimage{Lavender, very thick, no markers}
\addlegendimage{Violet, very thick, no markers}
\addlegendimage{BurntOrange, dotted, very thick, no markers}

 
\addplot[smooth, black, very thick] table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data3.dat};
\addplot[smooth, BurntOrange, dotted, very thick] table [x = {t4}, y = {a4}] {data3.dat};
\addplot[smooth, Violet, very thick] table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data3.dat};
  

    
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

    
    
    
    
    \begin{frame}

 \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.34]
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={
        group name=rzrxcomp,
        group size=1 by 3,
        xlabels at=edge bottom,
        ylabels at=edge left,
        vertical sep=4em
        },
        xmin = 0, xmax = 2,
        ymin = 0.8, ymax = 1,
        xtick distance = 0.2,
        ytick distance = 0.2,
        xlabel={$time\;[s]$},
        ylabel={$mass$},
        grid = both,
        grid style = {dotted},
        minor tick num = 1,
        major grid style = {lightgray!75},
        minor grid style = {lightgray!75},
        width = 0.85\textwidth,
        height = 0.50\textwidth,
        %scale only axis,
        %legend cell align = {left},
        %legend pos = north east
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=2},
        legend cell align = {left},
    ]
        
     \nextgroupplot
    
    \addplot[smooth, black, very thick] table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data1.dat};
    \addplot[smooth, Lavender, very thick] table [x = {t2}, y = {a2}] {data1.dat};
    \addplot[smooth, Violet, very thick] table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data1.dat};
    
    
    
    \nextgroupplot
    
    \addplot[smooth, black, very thick] table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data2.dat};
    \addplot[smooth, BurntOrange, dotted, very thick] table [x = {t4}, y = {a4}] {data2.dat};
    \addplot[smooth, Violet, very thick] table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data2.dat};
    
    
    
    \nextgroupplot[legend entries={n1,n2,n3,n4}]
    
    
    
    \addlegendimage{black, very thick, no markers}
    \addlegendimage{Lavender, very thick, no markers}
    \addlegendimage{Violet, very thick, no markers}
    \addlegendimage{BurntOrange, dotted, very thick, no markers}
    
     
    \addplot[smooth, black, very thick] table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data3.dat};
    \addplot[smooth, BurntOrange, dotted, very thick] table [x = {t4}, y = {a4}] {data3.dat};
    \addplot[smooth, Violet, very thick] table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data3.dat};
      
    
        
    \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

    \end{frame}

    
    
    
    \end{document}
```

I've tried to provide a similar situation of my WE. The problem is the following: when I try to compile the frame, plots are visualized in this way:

[image]

On the other hand, if I put a single group of plot in a standalone frame, I get the following:

[image]

How could I get the visualization of the three columns plots with the proportion shown on the second image? It has to do with column spacing?

Comment: You should really have another look at your code. As it is presented here, it does not compile. E.g. there is an `\end{document}` right in the middle of the code. Also, note that we do not have access to your `logo.jpg` and it is also not required, so I suggest you remove all the code related to the titleframe. And on a sidenote: Why did you use a floating environment -- `figure` -- on a beamer-slide? That makes no sense to me, as it is usually not required or desired on a slide.

Comment: To save some time when compiling, I also highly suggest you take a look at the `externalize` option of `tikz`. To further reduce the number of packages required in your example, note that the `beamer` class already loads some of them by default and you do not need to load them (unless you need to specify any options), which includes `graphicx` and `xcolor`.

Comment: @MarkusG. thanks for the warnings. Now the MWE should work properly, without useless frames. I've also added the "standalone" frame, to point out the visualization  differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, turns out your problem was quite obvious. Let me explain: The graphs in the lower frame are sized relative to a full-width column. The graphs in the upper frame are sized relative to a column of a third of the textwidth. The numbers become clear, when you use identical `scale`s of `0.34`. Then the full column width is `0.85\textwidth` and the graph in the column with a third of the width need to be larger by a factor of 3 to compensate for the smaller textwidth, i.e. `2.55\textwidth`.

For your code this means you can do something like this (I included some optimisation to your layout, e.g. using a `\pgfplotsset` to avoid redundant code):

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames, aspectratio=169, 9pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{FiraSans}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\usepackage{pgf,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps,groupplots,dateplot}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace} 

\begin{filecontents*}{data1.dat}
    t1       a1              t2       a2               t3        a3 
    0.142    1.000           0.154    1.000            0.139     0.995
    0.284    1.000           0.308    1.000            0.279     0.990
    0.426    1.000           0.461    1.000            0.418     0.989
    0.569    1.000           0.615    1.000            0.558     0.989
    0.711    1.000           0.769    1.000            0.697     0.989
    0.853    1.000           0.923    1.000            0.836     0.989
    0.995    1.000           1.077    1.000            0.976     0.989
    1.137    1.000           1.230    1.000            1.115     0.989
    1.279    1.000           1.384    1.000            1.255     0.989
    1.422    0.995           1.538    1.000            1.394     0.986
    1.564    0.990           1.692    1.000            1.534     0.981  
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{data2.dat}
    t1       a1              t4       a4               t3        a3
    3.554    0.920           3.845    0.950            3.485     0.913
    3.696    0.915           3.999    0.945            3.625     0.908
    3.838    0.910           4.153    0.939            3.764     0.903
    3.980    0.905           4.306    0.934            3.904     0.898
    4.123    0.900           4.460    0.929            4.043     0.893
    4.265    0.895           4.614    0.923            4.182     0.888
    4.407    0.890           4.768    0.918            4.322     0.883
    4.549    0.885           4.922    0.912            4.461     0.878
    4.691    0.880           5.075    0.907            4.601     0.873
    4.833    0.875           5.229    0.902            4.740     0.868
    4.976    0.870           5.383    0.896            4.880     0.864
    5.118    0.865           5.537    0.891            5.019     0.859
    5.260    0.860           5.691    0.885            5.158     0.854    
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{data3.dat}
    t1       a1              t4       a4               t3        a3
    3.554    0.920           3.845    0.950            3.485     0.913
    3.696    0.915           3.999    0.945            3.625     0.908
    3.838    0.910           4.153    0.939            3.764     0.903
    3.980    0.905           4.306    0.934            3.904     0.898
    4.123    0.900           4.460    0.929            4.043     0.893
    4.265    0.895           4.614    0.923            4.182     0.888
    4.407    0.890           4.768    0.918            4.322     0.883
    4.549    0.885           4.922    0.912            4.461     0.878
    4.691    0.880           5.075    0.907            4.601     0.873
    4.833    0.875           5.229    0.902            4.740     0.868
    4.976    0.870           5.383    0.896            4.880     0.864
    5.118    0.865           5.537    0.891            5.019     0.859
    5.260    0.860           5.691    0.885            5.158     0.854    
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{myscheme}{
    smooth, black, very thick\\
    smooth, Lavender, very thick\\
    smooth, BurntOrange, dotted, very thick\\
    smooth, Violet, very thick\\    
}

\pgfplotsset{xmin = 0, xmax = 2,
    ymin = 0.8, ymax = 1,
    xtick distance = 0.2,
    ytick distance = 0.2,
    xlabel={$time\;[s]$},
    ylabel={$mass$},
    grid = both,
    grid style = {dotted},
    minor tick num = 1,
    major grid style = {lightgray!75},
    minor grid style = {lightgray!75},
    width = 2.55\textwidth,
    height = 1.5\textwidth,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=2},
    legend cell align = {left},
    cycle list name=myscheme,
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{0.32\textwidth}
                \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.34]
                    \begin{groupplot}[group style={
                            group name=rzrxcomp,
                            group size=1 by 3,
                            xlabels at=edge bottom,
                            ylabels at=edge left,
                            vertical sep=4em
                        }
                        ]
                        \nextgroupplot
                        \addplot table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data1.dat};
                        \addplot table [x = {t2}, y = {a2}] {data1.dat};
                        \addplot table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data1.dat};
                        \nextgroupplot
                        \addplot table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data2.dat};
                        \addplot table [x = {t4}, y = {a4}] {data2.dat};
                        \addplot table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data2.dat};
                        \nextgroupplot[legend entries={n1,n2,n3,n4}]
                        \addlegendimage{black, very thick, no markers}
                        \addlegendimage{Lavender, very thick, no markers}
                        \addlegendimage{Violet, very thick, no markers}
                        \addlegendimage{BurntOrange, dotted, very thick, no markers}
                        \addplot table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data3.dat};
                        \addplot table [x = {t4}, y = {a4}] {data3.dat};
                        \addplot table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data3.dat};
                    \end{groupplot}
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{0.32\textwidth}
                \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.34]
                    \begin{groupplot}[group style={
                            group name=rzrxcomp,
                            group size=1 by 3,
                            xlabels at=edge bottom,
                            ylabels at=edge left,
                            vertical sep=4em
                        }
                        ]
                        \nextgroupplot
                        \addplot table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data1.dat};
                        \addplot table [x = {t2}, y = {a2}] {data1.dat};
                        \addplot table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data1.dat};
                        \nextgroupplot
                        \addplot table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data2.dat};
                        \addplot table [x = {t4}, y = {a4}] {data2.dat};
                        \addplot table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data2.dat};
                        \nextgroupplot[legend entries={n1,n2,n3,n4}]
                        \addlegendimage{black, very thick, no markers}
                        \addlegendimage{Lavender, very thick, no markers}
                        \addlegendimage{Violet, very thick, no markers}
                        \addlegendimage{BurntOrange, dotted, very thick, no markers}
                        \addplot table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data3.dat};
                        \addplot table [x = {t4}, y = {a4}] {data3.dat};
                        \addplot table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data3.dat};
                    \end{groupplot}
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{0.32\textwidth}
                \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.34]
                    \begin{groupplot}[group style={
                            group name=rzrxcomp,
                            group size=1 by 3,
                            xlabels at=edge bottom,
                            ylabels at=edge left,
                            vertical sep=4em
                        }]
                        \nextgroupplot      
                        \addplot table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data1.dat};
                        \addplot table [x = {t2}, y = {a2}] {data1.dat};
                        \addplot table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data1.dat};
                        \nextgroupplot
                        \addplot table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data2.dat};
                        \addplot table [x = {t4}, y = {a4}] {data2.dat};
                        \addplot table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data2.dat};
                        \nextgroupplot[legend entries={n1,n2,n3,n4}]
                        \addlegendimage{black, very thick, no markers}
                        \addlegendimage{Lavender, very thick, no markers}
                        \addlegendimage{Violet, very thick, no markers}
                        \addlegendimage{BurntOrange, dotted, very thick, no markers}
                        \addplot table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data3.dat};
                        \addplot table [x = {t4}, y = {a4}] {data3.dat};
                        \addplot table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data3.dat};
                    \end{groupplot}
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.34]
            \begin{groupplot}[group style={
                    group name=rzrxcomp,
                    group size=1 by 3,
                    xlabels at=edge bottom,
                    ylabels at=edge left,
                    vertical sep=4em
                },
                width = 0.85\textwidth,
                height = 0.50\textwidth,
                ]
                \nextgroupplot
                \addplot[smooth, black, very thick] table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data1.dat};
                \addplot[smooth, Lavender, very thick] table [x = {t2}, y = {a2}] {data1.dat};
                \addplot[smooth, Violet, very thick] table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data1.dat};
                \nextgroupplot
                \addplot[smooth, black, very thick] table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data2.dat};
                \addplot[smooth, BurntOrange, dotted, very thick] table [x = {t4}, y = {a4}] {data2.dat};
                \addplot[smooth, Violet, very thick] table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data2.dat};    
                \nextgroupplot[legend entries={n1,n2,n3,n4}]
                \addlegendimage{black, very thick, no markers}
                \addlegendimage{Lavender, very thick, no markers}
                \addlegendimage{Violet, very thick, no markers}
                \addlegendimage{BurntOrange, dotted, very thick, no markers}
                \addplot[smooth, black, very thick] table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data3.dat};
                \addplot[smooth, BurntOrange, dotted, very thick] table [x = {t4}, y = {a4}] {data3.dat};
                \addplot[smooth, Violet, very thick] table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data3.dat};
            \end{groupplot}
        \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @MarkusG. , you have given me a really big help! Have a nice day